# Friendly URLs remain with the old portion of the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I started to use friendly URL but I have two problems.

I have a link pointing to www.mywebsite.com/articles.php/321312/some-text-here

When I click on this link, on the next page all my links remains with a portion of the url.

For example, the clickable logo image points to www.mywebsite.com/articles/321312/index.php instead of www.mywebsite.com/index.php

Another problem is that articles.php only works with the .php extension.

My htaccess here

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
  RedirectMatch ^/$ /articles/
  RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php  [L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /articles.php?id=$2&desc=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /articles/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ articles.php?id=$2&desc=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

You must also add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: it works partially but great, except for the PHP extension. It redirects to 404 when I type without .php

Comment: Can you comment out `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` line and retest

Comment: Did you try that?